# actively invoke the yellow light bulb pycharm

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

I know alt+enter is the way to invoke a list of intentions/inspections when the yellow light bulb appear in pycharm. But sometimes I met a function without type hinting and I would like to add the type hinting automatically using pycharm but the problem is the yellow light bulb does not appear automatically all the time even when there is a type hinting missing for a function and there is already a wave unterline which marks this missing hint.  Is there a way to invoke the yellow light bulb automatically by a shortcut or by menu?